# In consistent results returned with white space in query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Using NEST.

I have the following code.

```
QueryContainerDescriptor<ProductIndex> q
var queryContainer = new QueryContainer();

queryContainer &= q.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.Code).Query(parameters.Code));
```

#### I would like to have both these criteria

code=FRUIT 12 //with space

code=FRUIT12  //no space

*Return products 1 and 2*

#### Currently

I get products 1 and 2 if I set code=FRUIT 12 //with space

and I only get product 2 if I set code=FRUIT12  //no space

Sample data
Products

```
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "APPLE",
            "code": "FRUIT 12"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "ORANGE",
            "code": "FRUIT12"
        }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

by default, a string field will have a `standard` tokenizer, that will emit a single token "FRUIT12" for the "FRUIT12" input.

You need to use a [word_delimiter token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html) in your field analyzer to allow the behavior your are expecting :

```
GET _analyze
{
  "text": "FRUIT12",
  "tokenizer": "standard"
}
```

gives

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "FRUIT12",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

----------- and

```
GET _analyze
{
  "text": "FRUIT12",
  "tokenizer": "standard",
  "filters": ["word_delimiter"]
}
```

gives

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "FRUIT",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "12",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

If your add the word_delimiter token filter on your field, any search query on this field will also have the word_delimiter token filter enabled ( unless you override it with search_analyzer option in the mapping )

so `"FRUIT12"` mono-term query will be "translated" to `["FRUIT", "12"]` multi term query.